# How to install ubuntu and windows on a non-bootable drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I recently purchased a PCIe ssd that unfortunately isn't showing up as bootable because it seems my motherboard doesn't support NVMe.
What I would like to do is leave my bootloader on a SATA hard drive and then move all the OS data to the PCIe ssd.

With linux, would it be sufficient to put the bootloader on the SATA drive or would I also need to put the /boot folder on the SATA drive?

With windows, would I be able to move everything to the SSD and then point grub to the windows install, or would I need to leave the 100mb system reserved drive on the SATA drive?  Also how would I update windows to know that the new drive is the C drive?